# I got some errors with dependency's But there is no dependency's with that name in puspec.yaml But has in pubspec.lock file

Tags: flutter, dart, integration

The Error Message Is:
/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:133:58: Error: The method 'markNeedsPlacement' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.

- 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsPlacement'.
  if (targetParent is RenderLayoutGrid) targetParent.markNeedsPlacement();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/placement.dart:134:54: Error: The method 'markNeedsLayout' isn't defined for the class 'AbstractNode?'.
- 'AbstractNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/node.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsLayout'.
  if (targetParent is RenderObject) targetParent.markNeedsLayout();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/layout_grid.dart:212:20: Error: Inferred type argument 'AutoPlacement' doesn't conform to the bound 'Enum?' of the type variable 'T' on 'EnumProperty'.
- 'AutoPlacement' is from 'package:flutter_layout_grid/src/widgets/layout_grid.dart' ('/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_layout_grid-1.0.6/lib/src/widgets/layout_grid.dart').
- 'Enum' is from 'dart:core'.
  Try specifying type arguments explicitly so that they conform to the bounds.
  properties.add(EnumProperty('autoPlacement', autoPlacement));
  ^
  ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2258:20: Context: This is the type variable whose bound isn't conformed to.
  class EnumProperty<T extends Enum?> extends DiagnosticsProperty {
  ^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Source\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1350
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Source\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 35s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

A solution for this

Comment: Have you recently updated your Flutter SDK? If yes, try flutter pub upgrade

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try these step

**First option**

- flutter clean
- Delete the pubspec.lock file
- flutter pub get
- cd ios
- pod install
- In Android studio, try to open android folder

android studio will install necessary dependency.

- After the build finished running, click
- build/clean in android studio
- build/rebuild

then you can try to run your project again.

**Option two**

- flutter clean
- Delete the pubspec.lock file
- flutter pub get
- flutter upgrade